# Bootstrap Accordion is not closing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I applied the accordion to html page its opening the sections but its not closing. I am using bootstrap.min.js version 3.2.

The below code also is not working. When I click on the link or button div will open but not closing.

### Demo code is

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
                Collapsible Group Item #1
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                Anim pariatur cliche...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
                Collapsible Group Item #2
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                Anim pariatur cliche...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please make a working snippet with your code. The accordion should open when add class `in` and close when removing it

Comment: I see you changed bootstrap class names, like panel-group to accordion-group, panel-heading to accordion-heading. Can you share here your bootstrap js and css file link. Then hope I can help you. Thanks :)

Comment: You can see here bootstrap.min.js version 3.2. accordion example  http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.2.0/docs/javascript/#collapse

Comment: You should probably update to 3.3.7